# Zoom towards are mouse is over

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have found this script online which i though would help me to zoom in on an image, but zoom towards the mouse position. However when the mouse is positioned to the left this isn't the case. I feel like there is a simple change I need to make however I can't find it!

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
});

Vue.component('test', {
  template: '#template',
  data() {
    return {
      zoomMin: 1,
      zoomMax: 7,
      dragEventX: null,
      dragEventY: null,
      touchEvent: null,
      zoomPointX: 0,
      zoomPointY: 0,
      zoomScale: 1,
      zoomStyle: null,
      frame: 1,
      speed: 1,
      zoom: 1,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.image.addEventListener('wheel', this.onWheel);
  },
  methods: {
    onWheel($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();

      let direction = Math.sign($event.deltaY);
      let n = this.zoomScale - direction / (6 / this.speed);
      this.setZoomScale($event.clientX, $event.clientY, n)
    },
    setZoomScale(clientX, clientY, n) {
      const bounding = this.$refs.image.getBoundingClientRect();
      let mouseLeft = clientX - bounding.left,
        mouseTop = clientY - bounding.top,
        zoomPointX = this.zoomPointX || 0,
        zoomPointY = this.zoomPointY || 0;

      let leftPoint = (mouseLeft - zoomPointX) / this.zoomScale,
        topPoint = (mouseTop - zoomPointY) / this.zoomScale;

      this.zoomScale = Math.min(Math.max(n, this.zoomMin), this.zoomMax);
      let leftZoom = -leftPoint * this.zoomScale + mouseLeft,
        topZoom = -topPoint * this.zoomScale + mouseTop;

      this.setZoomPoint(leftZoom, topZoom);
    },
    setZoomPoint(leftZoom, topZoom) {
      let left = leftZoom || this.zoomPointX || 0,
        top = topZoom || this.zoomPointY || 0,
        leftOffset = this.$el.clientWidth * (this.zoomScale - 1),
        topOffset = this.$el.clientHeight * (this.zoomScale - 1);

      this.zoomPointX = Math.min(Math.max(left, -leftOffset), 0);
      this.zoomPointY = Math.min(Math.max(top, -topOffset), 0);

      this.setZoomStyle();
    },
    setZoomStyle() {
      this.zoomStyle = {
        transform: `translate(${this.zoomPointX}px, ${this.zoomPointY}px) scale(${this.zoomScale})`
      };
    },
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test></test>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="template">
  <div class="container">
    <img ref="image" :style="zoomStyle" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/crash.net/visordown.com/field/image/2020_YAM_YZF1000R1_EU_DPBMC_STA_001-70516%20copy.jpg"></img>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: It never zooms towards the mouse. The top-left zooms to the middle. Debugging this code would be much easier if you included a link to where you found it, so we have a better understanding of what it is supposed to calculate at various points. My gut feeling says that it is offset by half an image, but trying that it does not produce the right results.

Comment: After sleeping a night and looking at the code with fresh eyes, I think you are better off just rewriting the whole thing. This code was not written with Vue in mind it looks like. The variable `leftPoint` is weird, because `zoomPointX` was set using a different scale. The min-max setter of `zoomPointX` in the function below it is weird, because the resulting point is always negative. That might be your issue here as well. `zoomStyle` should just have been a computed value (as should a lot of other variables tbh).

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks for the advice, I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not zoom towards the mouse on the right either; in fact, if you put your mouse in the top-left corner you zoom in to the center of the image. Besides that I can at least identify that `this.zoomPointX = Math.min(Math.max(left, -leftOffset), 0);` only allows your translate to go left, and thus only allow zooming towards the right of the center line.

### Some debugging

Let's start with taking a step back and figuring out what we are doing here. The final styling is a translate, followed by a scale. The scale happens around the center of what you are seeing on screen right then, and the translate that happens before that is meant to move the image so the point around which you want to zoom is in the middle.

To properly debug this we need a better understanding of what the code is doing, so I first added some debug markers and disabled the zoom styling, so we can visualise what is happening without it zooming all over the place.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
});

Vue.component('test', {
  template: '#template',
  data() {
    return {
      zoomMin: 1,
      zoomMax: 7,
      dragEventX: null,
      dragEventY: null,
      touchEvent: null,
      zoomPointX: 0,
      zoomPointY: 0,
      zoomScale: 1,
      zoomStyle: null,
      frame: 1,
      speed: 1,
      zoom: 1,
      
      // Debugging
      imageHeight: 0,
      imageWidth: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    markerStyle() {
      return {
        top: `${this.imageHeight / 2 - this.zoomPointY}px`,
        left: `${this.imageWidth / 2 - this.zoomPointX}px`,
      };
    },

    boundaryMarkerStyle() {
      const middleY = this.imageHeight / 2 - this.zoomPointY;
      const middleX = this.imageWidth / 2 - this.zoomPointX;
      const height = this.imageHeight / this.zoomScale;
      const width = this.imageWidth / this.zoomScale;

      return {
        top: `${middleY - height / 2}px`,
        left: `${middleX - width / 2}px`,
        width: `${width}px`,
        height: `${height}px`,
      };
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Moved the listener to the container so we can overlay something over the image
    this.$refs.container.addEventListener("wheel", this.onWheel);
    
    // Temporary for debugging; I could also determine it dynamically and should if we
    // we want to be able to resize
    this.$refs.image.addEventListener("load", () => {
      const bounding = this.$refs.image.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.imageHeight = bounding.height;
      this.imageWidth = bounding.width;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    onWheel($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();

      let direction = Math.sign($event.deltaY);
      let n = this.zoomScale - direction / (6 / this.speed);
      this.setZoomScale($event.clientX, $event.clientY, n)
    },
    setZoomScale(clientX, clientY, n) {
      const bounding = this.$refs.image.getBoundingClientRect();

      // mouseLeft and mouseTop represent the pixel within the container we are targeting
      const mouseLeft = clientX - bounding.left;
      const mouseTop = clientY - bounding.top;

      // zoomPointX and Y represent what point we were zooming towards
      const zoomPointX = this.zoomPointX || 0;
      const zoomPointY = this.zoomPointY || 0;

      // This attempts to modify the point we are targeting based on
      // what we are zooming towards before and what we are zooming towards now
      // zoomPointX represents something that is calculated with a different zoomScale, so this
      // presumably calculates bogus
      const leftPoint = (mouseLeft - zoomPointX) / this.zoomScale;
      const topPoint = (mouseTop - zoomPointY) / this.zoomScale;

      // This normalizes the zoom so we can't zoom out past the full image and not past 7 times the current image
      this.zoomScale = Math.min(Math.max(n, this.zoomMin), this.zoomMax);

      // This should represent the point we are zooming towards (I think?)
      const leftZoom = -leftPoint * this.zoomScale + mouseLeft;
      const topZoom = -topPoint * this.zoomScale + mouseTop;

      // This function breaks its promise to set only the zoom scale and also sets the zoom point. :(
      this.setZoomPoint(leftZoom, topZoom);
    },
    setZoomPoint(leftZoom, topZoom) {
      const left = leftZoom || this.zoomPointX || 0;
      const top = topZoom || this.zoomPointY || 0;
      const leftOffset = this.$el.clientWidth * (this.zoomScale - 1);
      const topOffset = this.$el.clientHeight * (this.zoomScale - 1);

      this.zoomPointX = Math.min(Math.max(left, -leftOffset), 0);
      this.zoomPointY = Math.min(Math.max(top, -topOffset), 0);

      this.setZoomStyle();
    },
    setZoomStyle() {
      // this.zoomStyle = {
      //  transform: `translate(${this.zoomPointX}px, ${this.zoomPointY}px) scale(${this.zoomScale})`
      // };
    },
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}


.marker {
  position: absolute;
  border: 8px solid red;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.boundary-marker {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test></test>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="template">
  <div class="container" ref="container">
    <img ref="image" :style="zoomStyle" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/crash.net/visordown.com/field/image/2020_YAM_YZF1000R1_EU_DPBMC_STA_001-70516%20copy.jpg"></img>
    <div class="marker" :style="markerStyle"></div>
    <div class="boundary-marker" :style="boundaryMarkerStyle"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

### Fixing the center point

First of all, lets disable the functionality to clamp the zoom point, as we know it to be broken.

```js
this.zoomPointX = left;
this.zoomPointY = top;
```

Then lets focus on getting the center point right. To get this right, we need to actually determine which pixel of the original image we are targeting, taking into account we might have zoomed in already! We need to keep in mind that the translate function and the scale function always are on the original image.

We can determine the part of the image we are currently viewing with `zoomPointX`, `zoomPointY` and `zoomScale`. (hint: we did that for the debug marker already) `zoomPointX` and `zoomPointY` do not really represent a point we zoom towards, but more the translation we made, so I have renamed them to `translateX` and `translateY` for convenience.

The x coordinate of the pixel in the original picture we can currently see on the left side of the screen is calculated by finding the x coordinate of the middle point on the original image, then subtracting half of our viewport from it:

```js
const leftSideX = (this.imageWidth / 2 - this.translateX) - (this.imageWidth / this.zoomScale / 2);
```

The number of pixels from the left side of our viewport to the point, as it would be on the original picture can be calculated by multiplying the amount of pixels this viewport represents with the percentage of pixels from the left border we are

```js
const offsetX = (this.imageWidth / this.zoomScale) * (mouseLeft / this.imageWidth);
```

And then we get our `translateX` by calculating from the middle of the image again.

```js
this.translateX = -(leftSideX + offsetX - (this.imageWidth / 2));
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
});

Vue.component('test', {
  template: '#template',
  data() {
    return {
      zoomMin: 1,
      zoomMax: 7,
      dragEventX: null,
      dragEventY: null,
      touchEvent: null,
      translateX: 0,
      translateY: 0,
      zoomScale: 1,
      zoomStyle: null,
      frame: 1,
      speed: 1,
      zoom: 1,
      
      // Debugging
      imageHeight: 0,
      imageWidth: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    markerStyle() {
      return {
        top: `${this.imageHeight / 2 - this.translateY}px`,
        left: `${this.imageWidth / 2 - this.translateX}px`,
      };
    },

    boundaryMarkerStyle() {
      const middleY = this.imageHeight / 2 - this.translateY;
      const middleX = this.imageWidth / 2 - this.translateX;
      const height = this.imageHeight / this.zoomScale;
      const width = this.imageWidth / this.zoomScale;

      return {
        top: `${middleY - height / 2}px`,
        left: `${middleX - width / 2}px`,
        width: `${width}px`,
        height: `${height}px`,
      };
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Moved the listener to the container so we can overlay something over the image
    this.$refs.container.addEventListener("wheel", this.onWheel);
    
    // Temporary for debugging; I could also determine it dynamically and should if we
    // we want to be able to resize
    this.$refs.image.addEventListener("load", () => {
      const bounding = this.$refs.image.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.imageHeight = bounding.height;
      this.imageWidth = bounding.width;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    onWheel($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();

      const direction = Math.sign($event.deltaY);
      const scale = this.zoomScale - direction / (6 / this.speed);
      this.setZoomScale($event.clientX, $event.clientY, scale);
    },
    setZoomScale(clientX, clientY, scale) {
      const bounding = this.$refs.image.getBoundingClientRect();

      // mouseLeft and mouseTop represent the pixel within the container we are targeting
      const mouseLeft = clientX - bounding.left;
      const mouseTop = clientY - bounding.top;

      // translateX and Y represent the translation towards the point we are zooming towards
      const leftSideX =
        this.imageWidth / 2 -
        this.translateX -
        this.imageWidth / this.zoomScale / 2;
      const offsetX =
        (this.imageWidth / this.zoomScale) * (mouseLeft / this.imageWidth);
      this.translateX = -(leftSideX + offsetX - this.imageWidth / 2);

      const leftSideY =
        this.imageHeight / 2 -
        this.translateY -
        this.imageHeight / this.zoomScale / 2;
      const offsetY =
        (this.imageHeight / this.zoomScale) * (mouseTop / this.imageHeight);
      this.translateY = -(leftSideY + offsetY - this.imageHeight / 2);

      // This normalizes the zoom so we can't zoom out past the full image and not past 7 times the current image
      this.zoomScale = Math.min(Math.max(scale, this.zoomMin), this.zoomMax);
    },
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}


.marker {
  position: absolute;
  border: 8px solid red;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.boundary-marker {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test></test>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="template">
  <div class="container" ref="container">
    <img ref="image" :style="zoomStyle" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/crash.net/visordown.com/field/image/2020_YAM_YZF1000R1_EU_DPBMC_STA_001-70516%20copy.jpg"></img>
    <div class="marker" :style="markerStyle"></div>
    <div class="boundary-marker" :style="boundaryMarkerStyle"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

### Fixing the bounds and doing cleanup

The original min-max function that we removed earlier was, I think meant to prevent you from zooming to a point where you see white on the outside of the image (ala what *did* happen in the original when you zoomed on the bottom right).

We can do this by clamping the value of `translateX` and `translateY` to an imaginary rectangle that is half the width/half the height from each of the relevant edges. We start by determining the height/width of our viewport (hint: we already calculated this for the marker). The center is (0, 0), while the edges are variations of (+/- `imageWidth / 2`, +/- `imageHeight / 2`).

Afterwards, we just need to clamp the value.

```js
const viewportHeight = this.imageHeight / this.zoomScale;
const viewportWidth = this.imageWidth / this.zoomScale;
const exclusionViewportY = (this.imageHeight / 2) - (viewportHeight / 2);
const exclusionViewportX = (this.imageWidth / 2) - (viewportWidth / 2);
this.translateX = Math.min(Math.max(this.translateX, -exclusionViewportX), exclusionViewportX);
this.translateY = Math.min(Math.max(this.translateY, -exclusionViewportY), exclusionViewportY);
```

Finally, I took the liberty to move `zoomStyle` to a computed property. It saves on having to call functions in methods that have nothing to do with that method like you did. I renamed the main function to better represent what it does. I also added a `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hook, because your code currently leaks memory as the event handler is not removed.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
});

Vue.component('test', {
  template: '#template',
  data() {
    return {
      zoomMin: 1,
      zoomMax: 7,
      dragEventX: null,
      dragEventY: null,
      touchEvent: null,
      translateX: 0,
      translateY: 0,
      zoomScale: 1,
      frame: 1,
      speed: 1,
      zoom: 1,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    zoomStyle() {
      return {
        transform: `translate(${this.translateX}px, ${this.translateY}px) scale(${this.zoomScale})`,
      };
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Moved the listener to the container so we can overlay something over the image
    this.$refs.container.addEventListener("wheel", this.onWheel);
   },
  methods: {
    onWheel($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();

      const direction = Math.sign($event.deltaY);
      const scale = this.zoomScale - direction / (6 / this.speed);
      this.calculateZoom($event.clientX, $event.clientY, scale);
    },
    calculateZoom(clientX, clientY, scale) {
      const bounding = this.$refs.image.getBoundingClientRect();

      // mouseLeft and mouseTop represent the pixel within the container we are targeting
      const mouseLeft = clientX - bounding.left;
      const mouseTop = clientY - bounding.top;

      // translateX and Y represent the translation towards the point we are zooming towards
      const leftSideX =
        bounding.width / 2 -
        this.translateX -
        bounding.width / this.zoomScale / 2;
      const offsetX =
        (bounding.width / this.zoomScale) * (mouseLeft / bounding.width);
      this.translateX = -(leftSideX + offsetX - bounding.width / 2);

      const leftSideY =
        bounding.height / 2 -
        this.translateY -
        bounding.height / this.zoomScale / 2;
      const offsetY =
        (bounding.height / this.zoomScale) * (mouseTop / bounding.height);
      this.translateY = -(leftSideY + offsetY - bounding.height / 2);

      // This normalizes the zoom so we can't zoom out past the full image and not past 7 times the current image
      this.zoomScale = Math.min(Math.max(scale, this.zoomMin), this.zoomMax);

      // Finally, we clamp the center point so we always stay within the image
      const viewportHeight = bounding.height / this.zoomScale;
      const viewportWidth = bounding.width / this.zoomScale;
      const exclusionViewportY = bounding.height / 2 - viewportHeight / 2;
      const exclusionViewportX = bounding.width / 2 - viewportWidth / 2;
      this.translateX = Math.min(
        Math.max(this.translateX, -exclusionViewportX),
        exclusionViewportX
      );
      this.translateY = Math.min(
        Math.max(this.translateY, -exclusionViewportY),
        exclusionViewportY
      );
    },
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test></test>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="template">
  <div class="container" ref="container">
    <img ref="image" :style="zoomStyle" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/crash.net/visordown.com/field/image/2020_YAM_YZF1000R1_EU_DPBMC_STA_001-70516%20copy.jpg"></img>
  </div>
</script>
```

[image: Edit Zoom towards mouse cursor on scroll]

Comment: Thanks so much for that explanation, it helps loads. I noticed that when zooming out from the edge some white space is shown however

Comment: The issue is that the bounding box changes when the zoom scale changes, which messes things up slightly when `this.zoomScale` is changed. There is probably a fix for that by using `bounding.width / oldZoom * newZoom` since the bounding box will not update until after the end of that function.